# widget. is not working in flutter even though variable name is right , accessing in the statefull class inside the Widget build

Tags: flutter

I have this code:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
final String text;

const MyWidget({required this.text});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Text(widget.text); // Accessing `text` using the `widget` keyword
}
```

this is my  simple my code, but  `widget.text` is causing an error:

```
Undefined name 'widget'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name. widget.
```

Answer (score 2):

You have it wrong: you need to use the `this` keyword instead of `widget` since your in the class instance.

Instead of

```dart
return Text(widget.text);
```

Use:

```dart
return Text(this.text);
```

---

You would use `widget.` when you are working within the `State` class of a `StatefulWidget` and you need to access the properties of the widget in the corresponding `StatefulWidget` class.

This is an example of when you would use `widget.`:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  
  const MyWidget({required this.text});
  
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.text);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much , but my error was in framework.dart class that's why i was facing that issue for that i have copied framework.dart class from another device and put it here and simply upgrade my flutter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to utilize `widget.text` or `this.text` since this is a stateless widget.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
final String text; // the text to store

const MyWidget({required this.text}); // constructor

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(text); // returns the Text object from flutter
}
```